# Which matrix norm is being used?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, positive-semidefinite

I read somewhere (unfortunately I cannot find the source) a while ago that a Hermitian matrix $A$ can be made positive semidefinite by adding $\pm \|A\| I$, but I cannot remember which matrix norm is being used. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious one is the operator norm.

Comment: Is the operator norm the one that equals the absolute value of the largest eigenvalue of the matrix whenever the matrix is Hermitian?

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ \ $